# Downloading shared files from a shared Google drive

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a free Windows application in which I want to download some MP3 files from a shared Google drive folder, in case the user chooses not to download these files with the application (due to size considerations maybe). I am able to do this using the file download links. But there are hundreds of files, which means I have to know hundreds of download links.

Is there a simpler way just to select a file for download from this shared folder, using the file name instead of its link? I do know the names of all those files.

Below is a working code example to download and save one such file...

```cs
using System.Net;   

public static bool OnDemand(string pFile)
{
    string LsShare = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1iQt6Qk8bFSoCQIlfk3xGkwlEgU87lLqT";

    try
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadFile(LsShare, pFile);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not unless you use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list) as far as I know.  And that would require your application to log in, rather than just using public links. But does it make any difference if your app "knows" a list of file names or a list of download links? The computer doesn't care. Either way you need to provide the app with that list somehow, so it can download the current list of files.

Comment: P.S. I don't know if you're paying for your Drive account or what, but certainly in the free one it will stop you from downloading too much data in a short period of time, so that people don't abuse what is supposed to be a personal facility to be, say, a backend file storage area for their application! I assume Google would prefer you used one of their commercial storage services for that.

Comment: Wouldn't Google Drive APIs restrict download to just Google. Suppose I also want to download from, say, OneDrive or DropBox, once I get a working soulution to this.  By knowing the names means my app already has a list of files (track numbers used as file names). And I will only download a few MBs OnDemand, but from a large number of stored tracks.

Comment: Well I was thinking that you'd just use the API to get a list of download links, which you'd then feed to the code which actually does the downloading. So if you designed your code such that it can handle different sources of information about what links are current, then it can use Drive, Dropbox, and any other service you choose to mention.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the app to be able to go online and retrieve the latest list of links every time it starts up, rather than hard-coding them? Otherwise people would have to download a new copy of your app every time you added a file to the storage. Whereas if you simply hard-code the place(s) where the app can go to get a current list of files, the rest of it can be handled dynamically.

Comment: The only problem I can forsee with this, if it's a desktop app, is that in order to connect to the drive API as a specific user, you need a client secret key. And if you provide that key inside your .NET app, it's no longer secret, anyone who has a copy of the app has access to your Drive account.

Comment: So here's a potential architecture to prevent that: 1) You have your current Drive account with the docs in. 2) You have a small web-based app on a server. This app will, when requested, connect to your Drive account using the secret key (which is thus stored on your server and not accessible to others). It gets a list of the current set of download links from Drive (and optionally from any other services where you've got stuff stored), and returns that data in JSON format to whoever called the application. It could also return the name of the file associated with each link.

Comment: 3) Your desktop app has the URL of your web app hard-coded into it, and visits that URL whenever it starts up, downloads the list of links, displays them to the user, and then sets about actually downloading each file that the user chooses, based on the link provided. So effectively what you're doing here is using the web app as a proxy to securely connect to your Drive account. This also means the desktop app always knows where to go to get the latest links. Does that make sense, and suit your scenario?

Comment: Its is a desktop app. The user may select a track to play. He hasn't downloaded it with the app (I have kept the program and data separate to reduce download size). It is the program's problem to resolve the track address, download, and play it. It is doing it too but by using the track (file) shared link. My question is: Since the folder containing these files is itself shared, is there a way to download using the file name instead. That way I won't have to store a link for each individual file too.

Comment: No you can't download via the file name - mainly because in Drive, the filename is not actually unique. You can have many documents with the same title within a folder. (This is possible because Drive is not actually a normal filesystem directly, instead it's a database of files. Each file has a unique ID, separate to its title. How the file data is stored in the background is hidden from us. Drive makes it accessible via a structure of folders and files, to make it seem familiar, but unlike a conventional filesystem the folder/filename combo is not a unique identifier)

Comment: Anyway no I doubt you can simply visit the URL of the shared folder and get it to list all the files, because I think that will return a HTML page, not something your code can easily read.

Comment: Forget about the idea of downloading via the filename, and re-read my suggestion. I'm suggesting that you use the Drive API to get a list of objects which contains the ID, filename and the download link of each available file. Your application requests this list from your server, and then displays the filename to the user, with a download link which actually points to the link associated with the file. When the user chooses a filename, your app simply visits that URL to download the link

Comment: That way a) your user gets to pick from a list of human-readable file names, and b) your app doesn't have to store _any_ filenames, links or anything, apart from one URL, which never changes, where it can go to get the latest set of download links in order to show the user.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks for the replies and suggestions. Like I said I won't use Google Drive API, because I also want flexibility. But your suggestions has given me an idea which I will try now. I will store all the links in a text file which I can edit anytime on the Drive. My app only needs the link to this text file. Therefore, thank you again, but again I still do need the file links!

Comment: "I won't use Google Drive API, because I also want flexibility." ...it does _not_ reduce your flexibility if you use the architecture I described. The server side code could connect to as many different storage services as you choose to define, get the results from each one, and combine them together into a single set of results to give back to the application. Then the app doesn't even care where the links actually point to, they're just a set of URLs.

Comment: I never said you didn't need the links, but my point was that the links can't be by filename, they can only be the download links that Drive provides you. Perhaps in your text file you could make it JSON format so that associated with each link is a human-readable filename for the user to pick from. (I'm assuming you only want the filename so it's easy for the user to know what files they are choosing? You don't need it to make the actual code work.)

Comment: But you know this text file is going to be very tedious to maintain, unless you hardly ever alter your list of files. That's why making a little web app which automatically retrieves the latest list of files is much nicer, it automates all that effort away. And if you have a little database behind it, you can store a list of what data storage services it connects to, and what credentials it uses to do so, meaning that what services it queries is entirely configurable, and changeable anytime by you, without having to re-write any of the code.